# Android Voice Assistant reads hyperlink twice

Tags: android, google-chrome, accessibility

I started working on mobile accessibility and there is a behavior that feels very weird to me. When I put a SPAN or DIV within an Hyperlink, the screen reader reads everything twice. This is not the behavior I have on desktop using ChromeVox or NVDA.

With the follow page

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .title { font-weight: bold; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="https://www.google.com">
        <span class="title">Some title</span>
        <span class="description">Some description</span>
    </a>
</body>
</html>
```

When my phone reads this page, I get the following:

- Some title some description
- Some title
- Some description

I already tried the following recipe but it feels overkill to me:

```
<a href="https://www.google.com" aria-label="Some title Some description">
  <span class="title" aria-hidden="true">Some title</span>
  <span class="description" aria-hidden="true">Some description</span>
</a>
```

Is there any simple way to make the voice assistant read the text only once?

Answer (score 0):

Mobile screen readers tend to go through each segment separately so this in some part is down to assistive technology behaviour. To directly solve this issue you could add  `role="text"` to each span tag, to get the behaviour you want.

But this is still probably impractical if you have lots of links with same issue. I can't really be sure but it looks like you might end up with some really long links which isn't ideal for accessibility. Try only nesting the important text in the  element. If you need to make the clickable area bigger try using another technique such as z-index, or a technique suggested here - https://inclusive-components.design/cards/#thepseudocontenttrick

See also https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/link-purpose-in-context.html